# Is there a way to append a trailing slash to get_home_url() and get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )?

Tags: site-url, home-url

Both `get_home_url()` and `get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) )` don't append a trailing slash at the end. Is there a way to append it similar to `home_url( '/' )` other than `get_home_url() . '/'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trailingslashit` function to make sure your URL's always have a trailing slash.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/